# How to detect tap on Uitableview cell with uiview and uibutton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a table view and i am adding my custom uiview into the cell's content view.
The uiview has a uibutton. However i can add the uibutton into the content view when the cell is created.

I want to get the tap event on the tableview to perform some action. I also want tap event on the uibutton to perform a different action.

The problem is when i tap a row the button is also getting pressed and two events are triggered.
How can i get both the events discreetly? i.e tap on the tableview cell when portion the cell outside the uibuttons boundary is clicked.

Comment: is your button completely overlapping your cell area or not ?

Comment: No its not overlapping the cell area. Its just a part of the cell at bottom right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Button in cell in as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 13.0f, 13.0f, 90.0f, 90.0f)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cellView.contentView addSubview:button];
```

then you can get events separately

Comment: yes when you tap a cell all subviews shows their highlighted state but it doesn't call your button event.

Comment: if you are using a custom button then you have to set the same image or same color for UIControlStateHighlighted as you are using for UIControlStateNormal. This wil remove the hilighted effect.

Comment: Hey but the effect will be same when the button in question is pressed. How can i show the pressed state for that button?

Comment: pressed state is the highlighted state

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure two different events are being triggered by the same tap?  My understanding is that UIKit generates only one UIEvent and sends it to the top-most view in the hierarchy that responds to that type of gesture.  In this case, if the button is higher in the view hierarchy, as it probably is, it should be receiving the event message.  But, I may be wrong.

One solution to definitely avoid the possibility of two events being triggered, though possibly not the ideal, would be to deactivate row selection for the tableView, as follows:

```
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

Then, add a view covering the remainder of the tableCell & add a gesture recognizer to that view.  Since they don't cover the same area, there is no chance of conflicting events.  Of course, to know what row was tapped, you'd have to add an instance variable for both the button and the new view to hold the indexPath.  You would set the index path when you set up the tableCell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Hope this is helpful or gives you some new ideas.

Comment: saadnib's solution is much more direct.  I'd go with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `UITableViewCell` and add a button, here is an example class:

```
import UIKit

private let DWWatchlistAddSymbolCellAddSymbolButtonLeftMargin: CGFloat = 15

class DWWatchlistAddSymbolCell: UITableViewCell {

  private(set) var addSymbolButton:UIButton

  init(reuseIdentifier:String?, primaryTextColor:UIColor) {
    self.addSymbolButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    super.init(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
    selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"PlusIcon")!
    addSymbolButton.setTitle("Add Symbol", forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    addSymbolButton.setTitleColor(primaryTextColor, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    addSymbolButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
    addSymbolButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    contentView.addSubview(addSymbolButton)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  // MARK: Layout

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    addSymbolButton.frame = contentView.frame
    let imageViewFrame = imageView!.frame
    let imageViewMaxX = imageViewFrame.origin.x + imageViewFrame.size.width
    let addSymbolButtonX = imageViewMaxX + DWWatchlistAddSymbolCellAddSymbolButtonLeftMargin
    addSymbolButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, addSymbolButtonX, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

You can see the "Add Symbol" button at the bottom:

[image: Add Symbol Button Cell]

When you're returning the cell for the `UITableViewDataSource`, make sure to set the target for the button:

```
private func addButtonCell(tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell:DWWatchlistAddSymbolCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kDWWatchlistViewControllerAddButtonCellReuseIdentifier) as? DWWatchlistAddSymbolCell
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = DWWatchlistAddSymbolCell(reuseIdentifier:kDWWatchlistViewControllerAddButtonCellReuseIdentifier, primaryTextColor:primaryTextColor)
  }
  cell!.addSymbolButton.addTarget(self,
    action:Selector("didPressAddSymbolButton"),
    forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
  return cell!
}
```