# Long press event on button

Tags: iphone, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect tap on Uitableview cell with uiview and uibutton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674701/how-to-detect-tap-on-uitableview-cell-with-uiview-and-uibutton)
>   [UIButton Long Press Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event)

I am loading button through table custom cell.How do i identify whether user's single click or long press event on button?.

Comment: You can use `LongpressGestureRecognizer`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just google it and i got best answer from stack-overflow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    [self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [longPress release];

 [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

and event:-

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
         NSLog(@"Long Press");
    }
}
```

Comment: my problem is there is no viewDidLoad in custom cell

Comment: its not nesecory to add this method in Viewdidload only. in your custom cell you just need to add this above code in your costome cell code when you add button like in cellForRowAtindex etc

Comment: share your code i will edit it

Comment: Hi Nitin, I think this is the Duplicate Question, You should mark it as Duplicate instead of Giving Answer.

Comment: its a new user of stackOVerflow Bro and i also mention link of this answer and i just put method when they used in their code :)'

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by creating and attaching the UILongPressGestureRecognizer instance to the button.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];
```

And then implement the method that handles the gesture

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
         NSLog(@"Long Press");
    }
}
```

Now this would be the basic approach. You can also set the minimum duration of the press and how much error is tolerable. And also note that the method is called few times if you after recognizing the gesture so if you want to do something at the end of it, you will have to check its state and handle it.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)setLongTouchAction:(SEL)newValue
{
    if (newValue == NULL)
    {
        [self removeGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
        [longPressGestureRecognizer release];
        longPressGestureRecognizer = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        [longPressGestureRecognizer release];
        longPressGestureRecognizer = nil;

        longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:[[self allTargets] anyObject] action:newValue];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
    }
}


[undoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(performUndo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[undoButton setLongTouchAction:@selector(showUndoOptions:)];
```